# How do I came to know that a jsp is called by specific servlet not by other links?

Tags: java, servlets

My question is i have a `login.jsp` , a `LoginAuthenticate.java` servlet and a `home.jsp` page..here i am checking login details i.e., `id` and `password`, if the `LoginAuthenticate.java` certifies the user, it gets redirected to `home.jsp` page, and if it fails it redirects to `login.jsp` page again, now what i want to do is that if the `login.jsp` page is called by LoginAuthenticate.java servlet than it must also display a msg indicating **login failed** , i try with a `if` statement but i don't know how exactly i came to know that this `login.jsp` is called by that servlet??? Is there a method with `request` object by which i can compare the caller servlet name?

Comment: Ok as an exercise but for real apps I'd strongly suggest you either look into the standard declarative security framework that's part of all servlet containers, or a more sophisticated solution like Apache Shiro or Spring security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be going directly to a JSP page anyway, ideally.

In any case. The easiest way would be to set a request parameter in the servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("i_come_from_da_servlet_yo", "ohai");
```

Then check for the presence of that attribute in the JSP.

Comment: but with case of `response.sendRedirect("login.jsp")` there is always a new request object is generated??

Comment: @Asif Either (a) don't redirect or (b) put it in session instead (and clear it in the JSP), basically a "flash" scope.

Comment: ok @Dave.. `RequestDispatcher` would be more convinient to use i guess as compared to opening and closing session by just a redirection..isn't it?

Comment: @Asif Not sure what you mean by "opening and closing session"; putting something into session and removing it are each a line of code or two, and if you *need* to redirect, it's your best option.

Comment: Actually what i mean to say that session will be ideally _created_ after successful login for future needs, and if you are not logged in than what is the need of it?

Comment: @Asif The session exists as soon as you render a JSP page, unless you explicitly direct JSP not to create a session. Whether or not a person is "logged in" or not doesn't have anything to do with whether or not the session is useful. It could, for example, be used to hold messages across a redirect.

Comment: Yupp... i got the right way towards the solution the **_session_**..thanks..i'll further go through it :)